# How to upgrade an LG Stylus 2 to Android 7 / Nougat?

Tags: lg, 7.1-nougat

The phone I want to upgrade is the LG Stylus 2 with the model number LGK520K as it currently on android 6 and i want to upgrade it to android 7.

I'm after instructions that give me the steps required and the ability to download what I need for the upgrade.

From the [LG versions and updates](https://www.mylgphones.com/lg-stylus-2-k520-checking-the-software-version-and-update-history) page it appears the software is available for phones in other regions but just not my region.

1. [Koselas.com how to upgrade lg stylus 2](http://koselas.com/how-to-upgrade-lg-stylus-2-to-android-nougat-7-0-7-1/) - Looks simple but the download link is very suspicious
2. [apkmoded.com hot to upgrade lg stylus 2](https://apkmoded.com/download-how-to-update-manually-android-7-0-nougat-for-lg-stylus-2/page/1/) - I'm not after a moded version
3. [LGs opensource distribution](http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?types=ALL&search=K520) - No idea how to use the source code

Comment: What region are you in?

Comment: @william my problem is I cannot find the distribution I can only find source code

Comment: @William the region is Australia

Comment: I have only upgraded/downgraded a Nexus before and it was much simpler.  If the OEM isn't wiring over the air I wouldn't know much.